# Host a static site from file system to an url via hosts file

Tags: windows, angularjs, http, filesystems, hosts

I have [this static site](http://nescalante.github.io/pokedex/). When development, I am accessing it with the following url:

```
file:///C:/development/pokedex/index.html
```

But this static site works with angular, and when angular try to get any view via ajax, it fails becouse `Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes`.

Now, I tried to modify the [Hosts file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)) to try to access it into `localhost` or any other url different than `file:///etcetc`, adding the following line to such file:

**hosts**:

```
file:///C:/development/pokedex    pokedex
```

But when I attemp to access `http://pokedex`, nothing happends.

How can I debug my site without having to upload it to a server just to debug it?

Comment: You will need to set it up in IIS. You would add pokedex to the Host Name on port 80 for the site

Comment: Well, that just works, thanks! This question has no more reasons to exist